# Rails — Params with "dot" (e.g. /google.com)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to force Rails to consider a param with a dot in the value like `google.com` (e.g. `/some_action/google.com`) a single param and not `"id" => "google", "format"=> "com"`?

The parameter value should be `"id" => "google.com"`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

By default, dynamic segments don't accept dots - this is because the dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. However, you can add some regex requirements to the route parameters. Here, you want to allow the dots in the parameters.

```
match 'some_action/:id' => 'controller#action', :constraints  => { :id => /[0-z\.]+/ }
```

And in rails 2.3:

```
map.connect 'some_action/:id', :controller => 'controller', :action => 'action',  :requirements => { :id => /[0-z\.]+/ }
```

[Relevent rails guides section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints)

Comment: There's some problems with that regex. how about `/[\w.]+/` ?

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 4 I used:

```
get 'operation/:p1/:p2', to: 'operation#get', constraints: { p1: /[^\/]+/, p2: /[^\/]+/ }
```

it allows any character in both params (other than '/')

Answer (score 4):

And when used with the *resources* notation, it can be done like this:

```
resources :post, 
               only: [ :create, :index, :destroy ], 
               constraints: { id: /[0-z\.]+/ }
```

Tested in Rails 4.1

Answer (score 1):

We had similar case when we removed some part of an api path. Basically we went from `/api/app/v1/*` to `/api/v1/*`

We put this in our routes

```
match '/api/app/v1/*path', to: redirect(path: '/api/v1/%{path}'), via: :all
```

This was all fine except for some routes that ended with path params including dots. E.g. `/api/v1/foo/00.00.100` where `.100` got parsed into `format` and the remaining param only had the value `00.00`

We guarded this with some constraint on the params.

```
put '/api/app/v1/foo/:version', 
    constraints: { version: /([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/ },
    to: redirect('/api/v1/foo/%{version}')
```

Edit: we use rails 5