# How to create a Rails route with a dot at the base of the path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that's it's technically possible to create a path that allows any character in it by using constraints. However, I have found that it's impossible to create a route that has a dot at the base of the path, e.g.

```
http://localhost:5000/.well-known/acme-challenge/
```

This is the route I've been using:

```
get ':my_root/acme-challenge/:id', to: 'pages#letsencrypt', constraints: {my_root: /.+/}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222760/rails-rest-routing-dots-in-the-resource-item-id), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369654/why-do-routes-with-a-dot-in-a-parameter-fail-to-match). Then found this [blog](http://flip.netzbeben.de/2008/07/rails-routes-and-special-characters-like-dots/). And tested like `get '/:my_root/acme-challenge/:id', to: 'settings#advanced', my_root: /.*/`, and it worked. *segment constraints* can be written without using the `constraint` keyword as per [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints).

Comment: I read those posts and tried everything they outline, but can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: and you tried my solution also? Because it worked here.

Comment: Yes, it's the first thing I tried. When you say it works for you, can you elaborate on what path you are visiting? Is it the same one as mine, i.e. `/.well-known/acme-challenge/123`?

Comment: Yes, I did like `http://localhost:3000/.well-known/acme-challenge/123` ..

Comment: ok, thanks. I think there is something wrong with my configuration then.

Comment: @picardo I'm having the same problem - did you get it fixed? What version of Rails are you on?

Comment: @PatrickO'Grady I'm using 4.2.3. I haven't been able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [dynamic-segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) in blue you will find

> By default, dynamic segments don't accept dots - this is because the
>   dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a
>   dot within a dynamic segment, add a constraint that overrides this –
>   for example, id: /[^/]+/ allows anything except a slash.

you can try

`get ':my_root/acme-challenge/:id', to: 'pages#letsencrypt', controller: /my_roo\/[^\/]+/`

I hope that this helps