# Dots in urls in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this rule:

```
match '/xxx/:id/yyy' => 'aaa#bbb', :via => :get
```

and when I try it with (note the dot)

```
/xxx/123.456/yyy
```

I get a routing error. I found I should use requirements parameter, but it seems to work only for 1.X and 2.X versions:

```
match '/xxx/:id/yyy' => 'aaa#bbb', :via => :get, :requirements => { :id => /[\d\.]*/ }
```

Not working for me under Rails 3.0. What is the trick?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails — Params with "dot" (e.g. /google.com)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952235/rails-params-with-dot-e-g-google-com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already several questions for this issue, look around, I myself asked that.
Here is like I got it working (like here on stackoverflow, when you klick a Tag like ".net"):

get 'questions/tagged(/:tag)' => "clues#index", :tag => /.*/