# Having a dot in the id of rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes, regex-negation

I am working on Rails 2.3.11. If I have a url like http://www.abc.com/users/e.f.json , I expect the id to be 'e.f' and the expected format to be 'json'. Can someone please suggest a way to do it.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the route syntax in 2.3, but you can try adding a constraint to the format to disallow periods. This should help keep the format to only the last dot-separated segment, but if you leave off the format you are going to wind up with part of your ID being used as the format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails — Params with "dot" (e.g. /google.com)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952235/rails-params-with-dot-e-g-google-com)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because of the :format convention, Rails will parse all parameters without any dots. You can have [route parameters with dots](http://zargony.com/2009/05/05/routing-parameters-with-a-dot) if you want:

```
# You can change the regex to more restrictive patterns
map.connect 'users/:id', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => /.*/
```

But since both '*' and '+' regex wildcards are greedy, it will ignore the (.:format) param completely.

Now, if you absolutely need to have dots in the username, there is a pseudo-workaround that could help you:

```
map.connect 'users/:id:format', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :requirements => { :format => /\.[^.]+/, :id => /.*/ }
map.connect 'users/:id', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

The downside is that you have to include the dot in the :format regex, otherwise it would be caught by the username expression. Then you have to handle the dotted format (e.g.: .json) in your controller.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution similar to andersonvom's, but keeps it all in one rule (and uses some modern Rails routing abbreviations).

```
map.connect 'users/:id(.:format)', to: 'users#show', id: /.*?/, format: /[^.]+/
```

(Note the `.` in front of `:format`)

The trick is to add an optional format, `(.:format)` and make the id regex non-greedy so the format is recognised. Keeping it in one rule is important if you want to give the route a name, so that you can use it for redirects, links, etc in a format-agnostic way.