# Parameter part after . is missing (.com)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm trying to create a chat system here.
I created a MessageThread Class that extends from `ApplicationRecord`.
I want to fetch all the threads that are linked to a specific email, and return them in a json format, this is how I did it :

```
def show
    threads = MessageThread.where(thread_owner: params[:id])
     render json: {
        status: 'SUCCESS',
        message: 'Thread list fetched',
        data: threads,
     }, status: :ok
end
```

I logged the `params[:id]` and that correspond to what I've sent in my React front-end.

The problem here is that `threads` returns an empty array (I can translate this to there is no thread associated with that email).

Now the tricky part is that if I execute this in rails console :

`threads = MessageThread.where(thread_owner: "testmail@ki.com")`

It will return an array with 3 threads in it (all linked to that mail).

So why does this work in rails console but not in my rails controller?

EDIT : 
Here is my front-end that handles the request :

```
async requestThread(data) {
        await fetch(`http://localhost:3000//message_threads/${data}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
            })
    }

    generateJsonData = () => {
        this.requestThread(localStorage.getItem('email'))
    }
```

EDIT 2:
I just figured out that my mail extension is going away when coming in in rails.
It comes in like `mail@gmail` and not `mail@gmail.com`

Comment: Is `params[:id]` variable allowed to be passed in the controller? Don't you have any security methods for passing only required params from the internet?

Comment: Yes it is since when I output params[:id] it shows me the data I passed (explained in question above. I have `params.permit(:thread_owner, :title)` to limit what is passed but this don't affect an id passed into the request. I even tried to add `:id` but it don't change anything.

Comment: In the case of the app context, not console, how are you determining that `threads` is empty?

Comment: It returns nothing, I tried something like `puts "Threads are : + threads"` and it don't print anything. When it returns to my front end I have Array(0)

Comment: Yep, you did say already it returns nothing. Where did you put the `puts`? And was that exactly the `puts` you used? That one won't print `threads`. You'd need something like, `puts "Threads are : #{threads.inspect}"`. Did you try the `puts` right after the `threads = ...` assignment in your `show` method? And can you show the front-end code that is handling the json?

Comment: I added this directly after `threads = MessageThread.where(thread_owner: "testmail@ki.com")`
I tried `threads.inspect` and that returns `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` Added front end to the queston

Comment: Debugging with a real debugger is much more efficient than endless `puts` statements https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-byebug-gem

Comment: You could also try inspecting `params[:id]` to make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: @lurker I tried outputting that and it gives me what I want. I tried the same value in rails console and it shows me all the `MessageThread` I need

Comment: @lurker Added EDIT 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to fix this here : [Rails — Params with "dot" (e.g. /google.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952235/rails-params-with-dot-e-g-google-com)

What happens is that rails don't get the .com extension of my email, results in an empty array.
This is my route for the `MessageThread` class :

`resources :message_threads, constraints: { id: /[0-z\.]+/ }`