# Route cannot be found Rails 5.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

```
Rails 5.2.3
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
resources :devices
```

When I do rake routes, I get:

```
devices GET /devices(.:format) devices#index
device GET /devices/:id(.:format). devices#show
```

In my devices/index.html.slim, I have:

```
td = link_to 'Show', device
```

Which is what Rails automatically generated, when I created the scaffolding for the Device model (I am using the simple_form gem, and the SLIM gem)

When I go into the Devices Index view, everything works fine visually. The log file says:

```
Processing by DevicesController#index as HTML
  Rendering devices/index.html.slim within layouts/application
  ......
Completed 200 OK in 140ms (Views: 129.3ms | ActiveRecord: 7.2ms)
```

But, when I click on the Show link, for one of the devices, I get the following error message:

```
Started GET "/devices/1566432871.922924" for ::1 at 2019-08-21 17:47:13 -0700
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/devices/1566432871.922924"):
```

In the Index view, I also tried:

```
td = link_to('Show', device_path(device), method: :get)
```

Same error. Any ideas? This should be working as is.

Comment: Your id has a `.` in it. Could be a possible duplicate of [Rails — Params with "dot" (e.g. /google.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952235/rails-params-with-dot-e-g-google-com)

Comment: Yes, this was the problem.