# How to allow a dot in URL params in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using a typical Rails resources route: `resources :wallets`

Which would generally produce a show route of `/wallets/123`.

Instead of the `123` I'd like to pass in a string with a dot in it like this: `/wallets/example.eth`

But at the moment, Rails seems to strip out anything from the dot and after.

```
Processing by WalletsController#show as */*
Parameters: {"id"=>"example"}
```

How can I make sure the entire `example.eth` passes through to `params[:id]`?

Comment: Executive summary: add a `constraints` option to the route.

Comment: Following up on what was already said, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952235/rails-params-with-dot-e-g-google-com